# Function gives error translationMap is not defined

Tags: javascript, function

```js
window.onload = function(){
  function translationMap(a,b){
  ctx.translate(a,b);
 }
 
 function majMap(sens){
  var cpt;
  switch(sens){
   case 1:
    for(cpt=0;cpt<16;cpt++){
     var horloge = setInterval('translationMap(0,2);' , 100);
    }
    clearInterval(horloge);
    break;
   case 2:
    for(cpt=0;cpt<16;cpt++){
     var horloge = setInterval('translationMap(0,-2);' , 100);
    }
    clearInterval(horloge);
    break;
   case 3:
    for(cpt=0;cpt<16;cpt++){
     var horloge = setInterval('translationMap(-2,0);' , 100);
    }
    clearInterval(horloge);
    break;
   case 4:
    for(cpt=0;cpt<16;cpt++){
     var horloge = setInterval("translationMap(2,0);" , 100);
    }
    clearInterval(horloge);
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

But when I'm executing majMap(); it told me :

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: translationMap is not defined";

What can be wrong and how do I fix that?

Comment: Sry, i said "hi" at the begining of the message but don't appear :/

Comment: Why did you add spaces to the title?

Comment: Good, because we don't want all that noise. Please revisit [ask]

Comment: I meant the Hi and the Thanks...it is noise we don't need it in posts. And I've fixed your post as much as I could. Please pay attention to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string to `setInterval` which would require all referenced code to be in the global scope (`window`). `translationMap` only exists in the scope of `window.load`. Move `translationMap` outside of this method.

```
function translationMap() {}
window.onload = function(){

}
```

Furthermore, I would recommend not using a string for `setInterval`, but instead, actually pass a function:

```
setInterval(function () { translationMap() }, 100);
```

This should also work and is a better solution than requiring javascript to use an `eval`.

Comment: Thanks, to ask a new question in relation with this question, can i post it here or have i to remake an other plz ?

Comment: Please create a new question

Comment: Pas de problem. Bonne chance! :D